# ¿Como puedo obtener una palabra exacta de una list?

Tags: c#

Como puedo hacer para que SOLO detecte la palabra que está en w.name?

Por ejemplo si la palabra es "Corazon", que solo tome Corazon y no Corazonn por ejemplo.

Estoy usando así pero no solo me detecta las palabras, sino las parecidas como con una letra agregada y eso no me sirve.
Lo intente usar así:

```
if (Configuration.Instance.LogCommands.Any(w => text.ToLower().Contains(w.name.ToLower())))

if (Configuration.Instance.LogCommands.Any(w => text.ToLower() == w.name.ToLower()))
```

En ambos casos ninguna me ha funcionado.

Comment: Hola, que tal? Gracias por la ayuda, al final use otra manera.

Comment: Donde la comparto? Aun no entiendo como funciona esto n.n

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener todos los elementos de una lista haciendo uso de **Linq** puedes hacer esto:

```
var palabras = (from l in lista 
                where l.name.ToLower() == text.ToLower()
                select l).ToList();
```

En la **variable palabras** guardamos todas las palabras que son iguales al elemento por el que estamos haciendo el filtro. La **cláusula where** nos sirve para hacer el filtro por la condición que deseemos.

Para hacer uso de **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```